# jQuery slider: clone and delete element based on slider value

Tags: jquery, slider, clone

Just like the title says...

I'm trying find the best way to duplicate/clone a div based on the slider value; conversely, I'm also trying to remove added elements when the slider value is decreased.  Effectively, the slider value should always reflect the number of cloned elements displayed (stacked on top of each other).  Initially, 0 elements would be displayed.

e.g.

Element to be cloned:

```
    <div class="test" style="display: none">test</div>
```

Slider:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical

init:

```
    max: 20,
    value: 0,
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be honest, I'm new to jQuery and I haven't decided the best path to start...  The best I could come up with is a method using a function like this  [link](http://jqueryminute.com/duplicate-and-clone-elements-multiple-times/) but where I really get hung up is when removing.  I suppose it would have also been helpful to mention I would like to preform this function on a slide event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the stop event of the slider to calculate how many divs you need to add or remove.  I am just adding and subtracting div elements but you could easily clone as well.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/ggC8s/

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 0,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            var diff = ui.value - $('#content div').length;
            if (ui.value == 0) {
                $('#content div').remove();
            } else if (diff < 0) {
                $('#content div:gt(' + ($('#content div').length + diff - 1) + ')').remove();
            } else {
                var i = diff;
                while (i--) {
                    $('#content').append('<div>div</div>');
                }
            }
        },
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        }
    });

});​
```

As an alternative you could remove all the divs and regenerate them instead of calculating the deltas.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/ggC8s/3/

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 0,
        stop: function(event, ui) {

            var diff = ui.value;
            $('#content div').remove();
            while (diff--) {
               $('#content').append('<div>div</div>');
            }
        },
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        }
    });

});​
```

Comment: I think `.clone()` is missing in there. Also, the alternate jsFfiddle might loose any attached events. But this still is +1 for solid method.

Comment: These are fantastic and it looks like either will work for my case.  Is there an argument for one method versus another?  The 2nd looks a tad simpler, but looks can be deceiving to a newbie.  Initially, I was unsure of the method to use; clone seemed like the right choice, but I am happy to see an alternative approach that solves the problem.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH for this!

Comment: @arttronics You are right I didn't outright use a clone but that is pretty trivial.. Here is a jsfiddle with a clone just to get it out there:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/ggC8s/4/  The only difference is I've used css to hide it instead of inline css so that I don't have to change the css when I clone it.

Comment: @Dennis I think better in your case should be the one that is simpler and easier to understand for you. That being said, it also matters what you are trying to do with it.  The 2nd example deletes the entire list and recreates it which is why it is simpler but it is probably less efficient.  Either way, choose one and see how it goes.

Comment: @Dennis, show your thanks by Upvoting if the answer is useful as well as making it the accepted Answer. @lucuma, I mentioned `.clone();` only because it's part of the SO Question, trivialities aside. Thanks for the examples, as it helps me too! +1+1

Comment: @attronics, apparently I need to be a reputation 15 before I can upvote; once I get there you better believe I will.  I did figure out how to accept the answer though...